Issue in Octave plotting 3d
Hi I'have a problem plotting 3d in octave.
OS: ubuntu 22.04
octave 9.3.0
Just an example
               x=1:1:360;
               y=1:1:360;
               z=ones(1,360)*10;

               plot3,(sind(x),cosd(y),z);

If you see the picture you see half circle.
Using how graphic_toolkit gnuplot I see the whole circle but is deprecated.
How can solve the issue
Thanks

Sounds like a bug. Please report it so they can fix it. https://docs.octave.org/latest/Bug-Reporting.html

I see a full circle - Octave 9.3.0 MacOS/Intel silicon, image.
